# How to get amount of clients and ping before joining the server?

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm creating a game which when you click multiplayer mode, there is supposed to be a list of servers (i can do this), but i'd like to list look like that:

```
Server name          Players online/max players          Ping
Server IP
```

And for instance:

```
Death match NO TANKS           15/40               40 ms
192.168.1.101:7390
```

I created server from this YouTube movie: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgLRe7QV6QI&ab_channel=Brian

Does anyone know how to get these informations (online players and ping) before joining the server?

Comment: perhaps have the servers report that information when you collect the available IPs

Comment: You probably need to connect to the server to query that information. Querying a few bytes of information won't overload the server, even if it has the maximum number of players already.

Comment: @PMF i will try

Comment: IMHO, rather than having each client contact each server separately to ask for this information, it would be better to have a "directory" service that collated the list of live servers and received constant updates from each server. This will also allow you to use this data for monitoring and other other functionality.